# Saving Javascript objects to Chrome.Storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

This code for a Google Chrome Extension doesn't work. I am new to Javascript and I am not sure what the problem is. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**JS/jQuery**

```
var userV = serviceName + 'Username'; 
var passV = serviceName + 'Password'; 

boolean works = true; 

var User = {
  passV: password, 
  userV: username, 
  works = true; 
}

chrome.storage.sync.set({User : userV}, function() {
  console.log('');
});
chrome.storage.sync.set({User : passV }, function() {
  console.log('');
});
```

**Script**

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("userV", function (User) {  
    sUsername = User.userV; 
};

chrome.storage.sync.get("passV", function (User) {  
    sPassword = User.passV; 
};
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you expand on what "doesn't work"? Are you having difficulty saving values to `Chrome.Storage`?

Answer (score 1):

In your code  you are storing User and Password in the same Key Name hence you will get only Last assigned value,

as well as your retrieving the value by value not by key

**JS/jQuery**

```
var userV = serviceName + 'Username'; 
    var passV = serviceName + 'Password'; 

    boolean works = true; 

    var User = {
      passV: password, 
      userV: username, 
      works = true; 
    }

    chrome.storage.sync.set({User : userV}, function() {
      console.log('');
    });
    chrome.storage.sync.set({Pass : passV }, function() {
      console.log('');
    });
```

Script

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("User", function (data) {  
    sUsername = data.User; 
};

chrome.storage.sync.get("Pass", function (data) {  
    sPassword = data.Pass; 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

For more simplify, you can store the whole User object into the storage. When you want to store your user data, the code is like the following:

```
var userV = serviceName + 'Username'; 
var passV = serviceName + 'Password'; 

boolean worksV = true; 

var user = {
  password: passV, 
  username: userV, 
  works: worksV 
};

chrome.storage.sync.set({"user" : user}, function() {
  // Do something...
});
```

Then, when you want to retrieve the stored data, the code is:

```
chrome.storage.sync.get("user", function(data) {
  var user = data.user;
  var passV = user.password;
  var userV = user.username;
  var worksV = user.works;
  // Do something...
});
```

I think that you don't need to store each data item as each property. I recommend that it will be stored as one object.